# Tensorflow + Keras + Convolution2d: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I run the code about CNN in my machine, but it got an ERROR feedback.

The snippet of my code:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(4 ,3 ,5, 5, border_mode='valid' ,input_shape=(200,200,3)))
```

and I also try:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(4 ,3 ,5, 5, border_mode='valid' ,input_shape=(3,200,200)))
```

and the ERROR are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "/Users/liumengyang/Desktop/visual/pre-processing.py", line 61, in 
    model.add(Convolution2D(4 ,3 ,5, 5, border_mode='valid' ,input_shape=(200,200,3))) 
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 280, in add
    layer.create_input_layer(batch_input_shape, input_dtype)
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 370, in create_input_layer
    self(x)
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 487, in __call__
    self.build(input_shapes[0])
  File "/Users/liumengyang/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 410, in build
    self.W = self.init(self.W_shape, name='{}_W'.format(self.name))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you are confused with the syntax of tensorflow.

There is some typo in your statement,`model.add(Convolution2D(4 ,3 ,5, 5, border_mode='valid' ,input_shape=(200,200,3)))`,

**Try this** `model.add(Convolution2D(4 ,5, 5, border_mode='valid' ,input_shape=(200,200,3)))` if your want to have 4 filters which size is 5x5.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. 
Your suggestion is really helpful to me.
The problem is exactly the syntax error. 
Best wishes to you !